# java return to specific point in program

Tags: java

I have the next question. I have the program which has the structure:

```
loadContext();
showCategories(input);
showProjects(input);
showdetails();
```

On each step me as a user has the ability to jump to previous step. For example I press 0 and program returns to previos step. Press 1 - program starts from the very beginning. Is there any instruments in Java to come to specific point?

**EDIT:**
I have here the console application. Main method looks like:

```
loadContext();//Loads categories
showCategories(input);//shows available categories and ask for which category to show
showProjects(input);// shows all projects inside selested category and select which project to show in details
showdetails();//show selected project
```

Now I want to set option. For example, in *showProjects(input)* put 0 and see again categories, select it and see category. In *showdetails()* select 0 and get back to show categories, select one and so on.

Comment: Where ever you have the code for accepting input like the ones you mentioned `0, 1` you should put code to call the appropriate functions. For example `0` is first function `1` is second etc. So if I'm in the third function and I hit `0` when required, it will run the first function.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific for us to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

1. Wrap all your four methods in another method:

   ```
      private void programStart(){
          loadContext();
          showCategories(input);
          showProjects(input);
          showdetails();
      }
   ```
2. Then have a method like this:

   ```
      private void processUserInput(int selOption) {
          if(selOption == 0){
              showCategories();
          }
          else if(selOption == 1){
              programStart();
          }
          else{
             System.out.println("Unsupported option");                  
          }
      }
   ```
3. At end of each of your methods where you want to have this option available:

   a. Read option from users
    b. Call `processUserInput(input)` with input

Answer (score 0):

What about a switch statement inside a while-loop? Gives the user the ability to select the step to jump to. This is the instrument for any language, and not just Java, to get to any specific point.

I have used java.util.Scanner since you want it to be a console application, although in 2015 we tend to rather use graphical user interfaces or Web pages in order to do the job:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BackNForth {

    private static int input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("select: ");
        int sel = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
        while (sel >= 1 && sel <= 4) {
            switch (sel) {
                case 1:
                    loadContext();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.print("Cat input: ");
                    input = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
                    showCategories(input);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.print("Pro input: ");
                    input = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());                    
                    showProjects(input);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    showdetails();
                    break;
            }
            System.out.print("select: ");
            sel = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
        }
    }

    private static void loadContext() {
        System.out.println("loadContext");
    }

    private static void showCategories(int input) {
        System.out.println("showCategories " + input);
    }

    private static void showProjects(int input) {
        System.out.println("showProjects " + input);
    }

    private static void showdetails() {
        System.out.println("showdetails");
    }
}
```